# Adding serial number in my table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple question but I want to know the unique way of doing this. I have a model called `Employee` and I am doing a db query to search for active users by doing

```
Employee.where(:status => "active")
```

Now I need to display all these in a table. Everything works well but I want to serialize each values so I was using `id` till now, but when I do the query

```
@id = Employee.where(:status => "active").collect{|a| a.id}
```

to the db I get id's like this `[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 29, 30]` but i would rather want [1,2,3,4,5,6,...].

Please help how to handle this in my view file where I add my table's serial numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller/model

```
@employees = Employee.where(:status => "active")
```

In your view

```
@employees.each_with_index do |emp,i|
# emp holds your employee object and i will hold the serial number which you can display
end
```

Comment: `@employees.each_with_index do |emp,i|
puts i unless i == 0
end` 
This worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?:

```
@employee = Employee.where(:status => "active").order('id ASC')

@ids = []
@employee.each do |emp|
   @ids << emp.id
end
```

Comment: You have declared a local variable as emp and used @emp.id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local variable and increment it in the loop.
Or in this case where the ids are unique, you could do

```
@ids = Employee.where(:status => "active").collect(&:id)

<table>
  <th> Sl no </th>
  <th> employee id </th>
  <% @ids.each do |id| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= @ids.index(id) + 1 %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <%= id %>
     </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```